# How to remove spaces from char in C and print it to a new file?

Tags: c, file, pointers

I would like to read from a file and copy the text (in lower case) to another file called employees2.txt. The conversion to lower letters worked good, but removing the spaces didn't work. I got a few errors:

- file is not constant
- passing argument one of blanc makes pointer from integer without a cast

I already tried something out: I printed all elements of s[i] to the console and IF an element is empty it should write Element is empty (it worked for all values, but not for s[22].

Could you please help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int j,c;
char s2 [255];
    FILE * file = fopen("employees2.txt", "w");

void blanc(char * s);
int main (void) {
    
    int  i;
    char s [255];
    
    FILE * ptr = fopen("employees.txt", "r");

    
    i = 0;
    while(1) {
        
        c = fgetc(ptr);
        
            if(c == EOF)
            break;
    
        c = tolower(c); 
        s[i] = c;
        
        i++;
            }


    
    fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
}

void blanc(char * s) { 
     s2[j] = s[j];
    if(s[j] == ' ') {
        blanc(s2[j+1]);         
 } else {
    fputc(c,file);
 }
}
```

Comment: `fopen` call should be inside a function

Comment: Anyway, is this some educational exercise? The same can be achieved by using common command line tools

Comment: It's a task from my university. I declared FILE * file; global but made the fopen call in main function. Then I called in the while loop blanc(s); but its not working.

Comment: FYI, this is a recipe for an unchecked buffer overrun, a recursion blowout, and possibly both. Also, `blanc(s2[j+1])` is nonsense. `s2` is `char[255]`, therefore `s2[j+i]` is `char`, which is *not* `char*` the expected type of the argument to `blanc.`

Comment: I updated my function it is void blanc(char * s) { 
 j++;
 if(x[j] == ' ') {
  
  blanc(x);   
 } else {
  printf("%c", c);
  fputc(c,file);
  
 }
}

Comment: all characters are printed now but with spaces for instance: bla bla but I wanted blabla

Comment: What is the purpose the `s` array?  There is no need for it at all.  Read one character, lowercase it.  If it's not a space, write it to the output stream.  Repeat.